# How to fix error when adding string to input variables?

Tags: python

.It says invalid syntax on the ' around the docx.

```
y = input ("lektion :") 
print(y) 

document.save(y.'docx')
```

Comment: In your case, what does `document` indicates?

Comment: document.save(y+".docx")

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
y = input ("lektion :") 
print(y) 

document.save(y + 'docx')
```

Comment: Should probably be `.docx`

Comment: Yes, sorry... typo.